# How to use a TikZ generated figure as a LaTeX command with parameters?

Tags: python, pylatex

I have to create a tree of contacts in LaTeX. Contacts data is stored in a MySQL database and I'm using PyLaTeX to generate my LaTeX file. There is the issue: I've made a "fiche" class which will generate the TikZ model for the ID (picture, name, phone number, mail, etc.) and I would use it for every one in the database. For example, this is my goal:

```latex
\renewcommand{\name}{Geoffrey Fouine}
\fiche{l}{h} % where l and h are (x,y) of the "fiche" in the sheet
```

I know that you can create a command by using `doc.set_variable('fiche','command')`. And I've tested by giving the `doc.set_variable('france', pic)` the pic which is a tikz class, but without parameters and it works!

Unfortunately, I don't know how to do it with parameters (`l` and `h`).

```py
from pylatex import (Document, Command, TikZ, TikZDraw, TikZCoordinate, TikZOptions, Package)
from pylatex.base_classes import CommandBase, Arguments


class France(CommandBase):
    _latex_name = "france"
    
doc = Document('test fiche')
france = Document('france')
doc.set_variable('couleur', 'blue')
doc.preamble.append(Package('tikz'))


def rectangle(pic, l, b, r, t):
    pic.append(TikZDraw([(l,b), 'rectangle', (r,t)], options=TikZOptions(fill='\couleur')))
    

with france.create(TikZ()) as pic:
  rectangle(pic,0,0,2,3)
  pic.append(Command('renewcommand{\\couleur}', 'white'))
  rectangle(pic,2,0,4,3)
  pic.append(Command('renewcommand{\\couleur}', 'red'))
  rectangle(pic,4,0,6,3)
    
doc.set_variable('france', pic)

doc.append(Command('france'))

doc.generate_pdf(clean_tex=False)
doc.generate_tex()
```

This code generates this `tex` file :

```latex
\documentclass{article}%
\usepackage[T1]{fontenc}%
\usepackage[utf8]{inputenc}%
\usepackage{lmodern}%
\usepackage{textcomp}%
\usepackage{lastpage}%
\newcommand{\couleur}{blue}%
\newcommand{\france}{\begin{tikzpicture}%
\path[draw,fill=\couleur] (0.0,0.0) rectangle (2.0,3.0);%
\renewcommand{\couleur}{white}%
\path[draw,fill=\couleur] (2.0,0.0) rectangle (4.0,3.0);%
\renewcommand{\couleur}{red}%
\path[draw,fill=\couleur] (4.0,0.0) rectangle (6.0,3.0);%
\end{tikzpicture}}%
\usepackage{tikz}%
%
\begin{document}%
\normalsize%
\france%
\end{document}
```

Comment: The answer is pretty simple : creating other commands which will be used inside the "fiche" macro!